# Adding clang complete to Homebrew installed Vim on Mac

Tags: c, vim, clang

I'm trying to install [clang complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) to vim on my Mac, but when I open a .c file I get the following error:

```
Loading libclang failed, completion won't be available
Consider setting g:clang_library_path
```

Where do I set the `g:clang_library_path`? Is this something that goes in `~/.vimrc`?

My understanding is that I need to point it to this path:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to put this in `~/.vimrc`.

I had a similar problem when I upgraded to Mavericks and [added some extra logging](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/pull/357) to track it down at the time.

[I put the following in `$MYVIMRC`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/dotfiles/commit/fee2bb03c54315e280a6752280c723612ff01aa8):

```
let s:clang_library_path='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib'
if isdirectory(s:clang_library_path)
    let g:clang_library_path=s:clang_library_path
endif
```

This way `$MYVIMRC` works on non-Mavericks machines, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let g:clang_library_path='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib'
```

you may try this if '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib' is not exist